# I need a way to fetch the product filter options relevant to the user's current query

Tags: graphql, bigcommerce

I am currently using bigcommerce as a headless cms to manage our products. I want to add a feature to our site that gives users options based on product category or other filters they've already selected like the image shared below. I have looked through the api documentation and I fail to find an efficient way of fetching this data.

I just need to get the edges and nodes that connect my available filters with the options so I can implement the filtering feature into the marketplace, but no matter how much I look I can't find what I am looking. The goal is to get the data for available filters and filter options that exist for a given category. The relationship data exists and on the big commerce site they do what I am trying to do so there must be a method to this.

`https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-api-reference#definition-Brand`

`https://developer.bigcommerce.com/graphql-explorer`

This is an image from a bigcommerce site of the feature I am trying to replicate on my site.

[example of the goal I am trying to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7wcaw.png)

[the connection I am trying to make](https://i.stack.imgur.com/djtkD.png)

[graphql schema section relevant to my question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CY16x.png)

This is my graphql post request

```
    site {
      search {
        searchProducts (filters: {hideOutOfStock: true}) {
          filters {
            edges{
              node {
                name
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

This is my response.

```
    {
      "data": {
        "site": {
          "search": {
            "searchProducts": {
              "filters": {
                "edges": [
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "Category"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "Brand"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "Color"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "Size"
                    }
                  },
                  {
                    "node": {
                      "name": "Other"
                    }
                  }
                ]
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```